# Wrong proposition in "Atiyah and Macdonald"s book?!

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, formal-grammar

In page 6 of "Introduction to commutative algebra" write that:

$a \cap b = ab$  provided  $a + b = (1)$

But I think it's not true, by considering $a = b = (2) \in \mathbb Z_6$

Comment: If $a=b$, you don't have $a+b=(1)$, unless $a=b=(1)$.

Comment: Thanks, i don't have good knowledge about  English  grammer.i thinked : provided = only if ! :D

Comment: @2000 It's not “only if”, but “if”.

Comment: @ egreg : ok. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition can be reformulated as

> if $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=(1)$, then $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$

The word “provided” is used in the sense of “when it is given that”.

In your case $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=(2)+(2)=(2)\ne(1)$.